# What's the difference between unbounded wildcard type List<?> and raw type List?

Tags: java, generics, list

Could you help me understand the difference between *unbounded wildcard type List* and *raw type List*?

```
List<?> b;    // unbounded wildcard type
List a;       // raw type
```

Along with this can anybody help me understand what is a *bounded type parameter list*?

```
List<E extends Number> c;
```

Comment: Reading `Effective Java` chapter 5 helps a lot understanding everything about generics.

Comment: You can check [unbounded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html). This is called a list of unknown type.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here's a summary of the three:

- `List`: A list with no type parameter. It is a list whose elements are of any type -- **the elements may be of different types**.
- `List<?>`: A list with an unbounded type parameter. Its elements are of a specific, but unknown, type; **the elements must all be instances of some specific type**.
- `List<T extends E>`: A list with a type parameter called `T`. The supplied type for `T` must be of a type that extends `E`, or it is not a valid type for the parameter.

Comment: @List<?>: will the type will be defined with the insertion of 1st element??

Comment: From what I understand, Java loses all information about generic types when you compile your program, so they all end up as `List`. There is no type inference going on there, they're all Objects.

Comment: @Blindy: You are correct that there is no type inference going on and that List<?> basically means "Any generic List". But it really has nothing to do with losing type information at runtime. What you are referring to is known as "erasure".

Comment: "the elements must all be the same type" this distinction does not exist. the type parameter could be Object, in which case the elements can be any type

Comment: List<? extends E> what about this?

Comment: @newacct A more accurate phrasing: *the elements must all be instances of some particular type*.

Comment: The type `T` doesn't have to extend `E` necessarily. For example, it can be `E` itself.

Answer (score 20):

You should really look at Effective Java, Item 23: Don't use raw types in new code.

To use the example from that book, consider the following example... what if you have a collection where you do not care what types of elements are in it. For example, you want to see how many elements are in common between two sets. You might come up with the following:

```
public static int numElementsInCommon(Set s1, Set s2) {
  int result = 0;
  for (Object o : s1) {
    if (s2.contains(o)) {
      ++result;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

This example, while it works, is not a good idea to use because of the use of raw types. Raw types just aren't type safe at all... you could end up modifying the set in a way that is not type safe and corrupt your program. Instead, err on the side of caution and use the type safe alternative:

```
public static int numElementsInCommon(Set<?> s1, Set<?> s2) {
  int result = 0;
  for (Object o : s1) {
    if (s2.contains(o)) {
      ++result;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The difference is that you can only add `null` to a `Set<?>`, and you CANNOT assume anything about the element you take out of a `Set<?>`. If you use a raw `Set`, you can add anything you want to it. The `numElementsInCommon` method is a good example where you don't even need to add anything and you don't need to assume anything about what is in the set. That's why it's a good candidate for using the `?` wildcard.

Hope this helps. Read that whole Item in Effective Java and it will really become clear.

To answer the second part of your question... remember that I said when you use the `?` wildcard, you cannot assume anything about the element you take out of the set? What if you do need to make an assumption about the interface of the object you removed from the set. For example, suppose you want to keep track of a set of `Cool` things.

```
public interface Cool {
  // Reports why the object is cool
  void cool();
}
```

Then you might have some code like this:

```
public static void reportCoolness(Set s) {
  for (Object item : s) {
    Cool coolItem = (Cool) item;
    coolItem.cool();
  }
}
```

This is not type safe... you need to make sure you passed in a set with only `Cool` objects. To fix it, you might say:

```
public static void reportCoolness(Set<Cool> s) {
  for (Cool coolItem : s) {
    coolItem.cool();
  }
}
```

This is great! Does exactly what you want and is type safe. But what if later you have this:

```
public interface ReallyCool extends Cool {
  // Reports why the object is beyond cool
  void reallyCool();
}
```

Since all `ReallyCool` objects are `Cool`, you ought to be able to do the following:

```
Set<ReallyCool> s = new HashSet<ReallyCool>();
// populate s
reportCoolness(s);
```

But you can't do that because generics have the following property: Suppose `B` is a subclass of `A`, then `Set<B>` is NOT a subclass of `Set<A>`. The technical talk for this is "Generic types are invariant." (As opposed to covariant).

To get the last example to work you would need to create a `Set<Cool>` by casting (safely) every element in the `Set<ReallyCool>`. To avoid letting clients of your api go through this nasty, unnecessary code, you can just make the `reportCoolness` method more flexible like this:

```
public static void reportCoolness(Set<? extends Cool> s) {
  for (Cool coolItem : s) {
    coolItem.cool();
  }
}
```

Now your method takes any `Set` that contains elements that are `Cool` or any subclass of `Cool`. All of these types adhere to the `Cool` api... so we can safely call the `cool()` method on any element

Make sense? Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

On your first question, the difference between `List` and `List<?>`:

One significant difference between the two is that when you have an wildcard as the type, the type of the `Collection` is unknown, so the `add` method will throw a compile time error.

You can still get values out of the `List<?>`, but you need an explicit cast.

Comment: can you please elaborate the second part of the answer it will be very helpful if you do so..

Comment: @akf: I don't think that the risk of exceptions is any different.  It is just that an explicit cast makes the risk a bit more obvious at the source-code level.

Answer (score 1):

Both cases let us put into this variable any type of list:

```
List nothing1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List nothing2 = new ArrayList();
List nothing3 = new ArrayList<>();
List nothing4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

List<?> wildcard1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<?> wildcard2 = new ArrayList();
List<?> wildcard3 = new ArrayList<>();
List<?> wildcard4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

But what elements can we put into this objects?

We can put only String into `List<String>`:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("A new string");
```

We can put any object into List:

```
List nothing = new ArrayList<>();
nothing.add("A new string");
nothing.add(1);
nothing.add(new Object());
```

And we can't add anything (but for *null*) into `List<?>`! Because we use generic. And Java knows that it is typed List but doesn't know what type it is exact. And doesn't let us make a mistake.

Conclusion: `List<?>`, which is generic List, **gives us type safety**.

P.S. Never use raw types in your code.