# Java generics: what is the difference between <?> and skipping it?

Tags: java, generics

Maybe it is silly question: Let say I have

```
abstract class A<T> {
  List<Wrapper<T>> doStuff()
}
```

And I have `class B extends A<String>`  and `class C extends A<Integer>`

Now I want to have:

```
List<A> aces = list with instances of B and C;

List<Wrapper> wrapperedItems = flattened list of lists returned from doStuff() on all items in aces
```

At this point I don't care what type is within `Wrapper`.
And my question is: shall I use somewhere `<?>` or can I skip it? What is the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between List and List<?>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983489/difference-between-list-and-list)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360594/whats-the-difference-between-raw-types-unbounded-wild-cards-and-using-object-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `List<Wrapper<?>>`, you will be able to get objects out of the list, but you will not be able to add new items. The wildcard essentially correcponds to a type that is different from any other type, including other wildcards.

If you use `List<Wrapper>`, you will be able to both get list items and add new ones, but the onus is now up to you to guard for improper type casts.